# How to remove the text in the div?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="googlefy">    
<div class="skiptranslate">
    <div>....</div>
    <div id="">
    hello by
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">....<span>
    </div>
</div>
```

now i want to remove text hello by. how do i do?

when i using `$("#googlefy:contains('hello by')").remove()`. it remove all the html.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will only remove "hello by"

```
$('#googlefy').html($('#googlefy').html().replace(/hello\sby/, ""));
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what the OP asked for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you don't want to remove a specific text but need a generic solution, this code removes all texts at the start of the div :

```
var div = document.getElementById('yourid');
while(div.childNodes[0].nodeType==3)  
   div.removeChild(div.childNodes[0]);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uheror/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To be practical I recommend enhancing the document structure. You may add a class just for elements to be cleared.

```
<div id="googlefy">    
<div class="skiptranslate">
    <div>....</div>
    <div>
    <span class="clear_this">hello by</span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">....<span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you may remove the node (including the `<span>` tag) using `$('.clear_this').remove()` or keep the `<span>` by setting `$('.clear_this').text("")`

Also note that `id` in html shouldn't be blank when specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $(".skiptranslate").find('div:last-child').text().replace('hello by','');
```